# Rename file and overwrite it again

Tags: java, android, file

I'm trying to rename file on my gallery I'm using following steps

getting file path from device then rename the path , but it doesn't rename it on local path

I want to overwrite it with new name

```
             picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);// real pic path on my device after getting it from gallery 
         File photo = new File(picturePath);
         File newFile= new File(picturePath,"hhhhhhh");
         photo.renameTo(newFile);
```

Comment: Does it create this new file with old still existing, or what?

Comment: yes it still old name there , i want to rename it but it return false

Answer (score 0):

If picturePath is the complete path (path+filename), then on the second call you are trying to define the newFile object as (path+filename+newname). E.g. you have /some/where/photo.jpg and renaming it to /some/where/photo.jpg/hhhhhhh. I guess you need a getPath() there.

Comment: yes how to avoid /some/where/photo.jpg/hhhhhhh , i want to make it as /some/where/hhhhhh.jpg/

Comment: I guess because I have no compiler available right now, anyway I'd say newFile = new File(photo.getPath(),"hhhhhhh.jpg");